# How to have UIView update as a button in a tableviewcell is clicked

Tags: ios, swift, button, uiview

I have a tableviewcell class defined separately from my UIViewController file. Inside my UIViewController, I have a UIView that is part of the background of the app. I have a button inside the tableviewcell (so inside its class), and I want the background to change as I click the tableviewcell's button. How would I refresh the UIView?

Answer (score 0):

You should use delegate or closure to handle callback when you click tableviewcell.
Please follow the below link:

[Delegation in swift](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/posts/delegation-in-swift)

[Closures in swift](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html)